# Changing SQLite to PostgreSQL in Django cause Error 'cannot cast type bytea to boolean'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I had a project in Django that use SQLite as database and it works well. Now i want change my database from SQLite to PostgreSQL. i changed settings.py file and installed psycopg2. the problem is that when i want run `python manage.py migrate` i had error in CMD that says:

```
...
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type bytea to boolean
LINE 1: ...ansactionType" TYPE boolean USING "TransactionType"::boolean
```

and at django debug mode in browser shows this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /home
operator does not exist: bytea = boolean
LINE 1: ...ction" WHERE ("web_transaction"."TransactionType" = true AND...
```

this is my model in django

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
     Amount = models.BigIntegerField()
     TransactionType = models.BooleanField()
```

in my home view i use this query that error django debug mode indicates:

```
def homePage(request):
    this_user=request.user
    
    income = Transaction.objects.filter(user=this_user, TransactionType=True).aggregate(Sum('Amount'))
```

i can't find out why this happen when use PostgreSQL but works well in SQLite.

Comment: sqlite doesn't care about enforcing datatypes; postgres does, as do most other RBDMs. That said, I don't know enough django to understand the migration process, but I assume that at some point you changed the datatype of `TransactionType` and sqlite allowed it

Comment: That might not be the reason but the tradition in Python is to use snake case variable names without capital letters. `Amount` -> `amount`, `TransactionType` -> `transaction_type`

Comment: Maybe the reason is that you don't set a `default=...` on your BooleanField() `TransactionType` and so it does some weird things ?

Comment: thanks @lbris for your response. `amount` was my mistake in typing question and i correct it.

Comment: @lbris i added default value as `TransactionType = models.BooleanField(default=True)` but still shows same error

Comment: Please show the full traceback. If it fails during `migrate`, then please show the migration that is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason of this problem is `migration` file that automatically generated by Django. Database will create based on this file in Djagno. I checked the DataBase it self with its command line interface and see `TransactionType` type is byte instead of boolean and checked migration file in my project and see
`('TransactionType', models.BinaryField())`
this code as definition of my column and change type of it to boolean. Then i rest my database and migrate it again and my project works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a different `USING` clause in the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Depending on what you want, that could be

```
... USING ("TransactionType" IS NOT NULL)
```

or you might use a constant:

```
... USING (FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Django automatically gives you a database-abstraction API that lets you create, retrieve, update and delete objects and i didn't use `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: @user3480650 for SQLAlchemy, migrations are accessible scripts that you can edit. I assume the django ORM is similar - you will have to open the file and make the edit on the failing migration

Comment: i tried both `False` and `True` as default value in defining `TransactionType` and still shows same error!

Comment: I don't know anything about Django, so I don't know how to get it to do that. But usually such tools allow you to run hand-written SQL.